# Ruby: how do I use assert_nothing_raised?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

```
 assert_nothing_raised do
   @board.make_move(0,0,Board::HUMAN)
 end
```

and the docs say:

```
Passes if block does not throw anything.

Example:

 assert_nothing_thrown do
   [1, 2].uniq
 end
```

my make_move method:

```
def make_move(x, y, player)
    return false
 end
```

I get the error:

```
test_can_make_valid_move_in_the_first_row(BoardTest):
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

Comment: What testing framework are you using? Ruby's own unit/test? [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest)? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This following code works for me.  Does it work for you?

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'

class MyTestClass < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_something
    assert_nothing_raised do
      p 'hi'
    end
  end
end

Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(MyTestClass)
```

I think you are using assert_nothing_raised correctly.   Try replacing

```
@board.make_move(0,0,Board::HUMAN)
```

with something more simple, like

```
p 'hi'
```

and see if that works.  Also try commenting out all the other code in your test.

Answer (score 3):

It can be argued that you should never use `assert_nothing_raised`, as it does not actually test anything. See:

http://blog.zenspider.com/blog/2012/01/assert_nothing_tested.html

I've posted some further thoughts here:

[Why doesn't MiniTest::Spec have a wont_raise assertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499259/why-does-minitestspec-have-no-wont-raise-assertion)