# Why doesn't MiniTest::Spec have a wont_raise assertion?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

Ruby's `Test::Unit` has `assert_nothing_raised`. `Test::Unit` has been replaced by [MiniTest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest). Why don't MiniTest's assertions / expectations have anything parallel to this? For example you can expect `must_raise` but not `wont_raise`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

MiniTest does implement `assert_nothing_raised` in its Test::Unit compatibility layer, but in its own tests (`MiniTest::Unit` and `MiniTest::Spec`) it does *not* implement any test like this. The reason is, the programmer argues, that testing for nothing raised is not a test of anything; you *never* expect anything to be raised in a test, except when you are testing *for* an exception. If an unexpected (uncaught) exception occurs in the code for a test, you'll get an exception reported in good order by the test and you'll know you have a problem.

Example:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

describe "something" do
  it "does something" do
    Ooops
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Run options: --seed 41521

# Running tests:

E

Finished tests in 0.000729s, 1371.7421 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_0001_does_something(something):
NameError: uninitialized constant Ooops
    untitled:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Which is exactly what you wanted to know. If you were expecting nothing to be raised, you didn't get it and you've been told so.

So, the argument here is: do not use `assert_nothing_raised`! It's just a meaningless crutch. See, for example:

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/70

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/159

http://blog.zenspider.com/blog/2012/01/assert_nothing_tested.html

On the other hand, clearly `assert_nothing_raised` corresponds to some intuition among users, since so many people expect a `wont_raise` to go with `must_raise`, etc. In particular one would like to focus an *assertion* on this, not merely a test. Luckily, MiniTest is extremely minimalist and flexible, so if you want to add your own routine, you can. So you can write a method that tests for no exception and returns a known outcome if there is no exception, and now you can assert for that known outcome.

For example (I'm not saying this is perfect, just showing the idea):

```
class TestMyRequire < MiniTest::Spec
  def testForError # pass me a block and I'll tell you if it raised
    yield
    "ok"
  rescue
    $!
  end
  it "blends" do
    testForError do
      something_or_other
    end.must_equal "ok"
  end
end
```

The point is not that this is a good or bad idea but that it was never the responsibility of MiniTest to do it for you.

Comment: Great answer. `assert_nothing_raised` is a noop. You are better off avoiding it. Love zenspider's comment from his blog post: "This is exactly why minitest doesn’t have `assert_nothing_raised`. You wind up with file after file of useless junk tests."

Comment: Suppose you wanted to verify that some JSON that you were generated was valid and would be parseable, I've seen code along the lines of

   assert_nothing_raised do
      JSON.parse(my_method_that_returns_some_json)
   end

However I think that in the general case I agree with the above comments.

Comment: Do not name methods camelCase in ruby (testForError) but snake_case (test_for_error). But +1 for the answer: do not assert for nothing raised

Comment: I need assert_nothing_raised, for example, when I have a method that raises an ArgumentError with a descriptive message for bad inputs, and want to ensure that there are no false positives (i.e. it doesn't raise an error on valid input).

Comment: @KeithBennett Me too. That's why my answer provides a way of doing exactly that.

Comment: While in strict sense it's all true, if you write a test without assertions, just to make sure the code doesn't throw an error, you'd probably add a comment saying "this shouldn't raise an error", so having an assertion seems more consistent, lest we ditch all of them, because `assert` is the only one you really need... `assert_false` -> use `!`; `assert_equal` -> use `==`; etc... it's all syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 12):

If you need it:

```rb
# test_helper.rb

module Minitest::Assertions
  def assert_nothing_raised(*)
    yield
  end
end
```

And to use it:

```rb
def test_unknown_setter
  assert_nothing_raised do
    result.some_silly_column_name = 'value'
  end
end
```

Comment: Good one! I'm a big fan of the monkey patch.

Answer (score 3):

This bothered me enough to dig into the MiniTest sources and provide an implementation in my `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
module MiniTest
  module Assertions
    def refute_raises *exp
      msg = "#{exp.pop}.\n" if String === exp.last

      begin
        yield
      rescue MiniTest::Skip => e
        return e if exp.include? MiniTest::Skip
        raise e
      rescue Exception => e
        exp = exp.first if exp.size == 1
        flunk "unexpected exception raised: #{e}"
      end

    end
  end
  module Expectations
    infect_an_assertion :refute_raises, :wont_raise
  end
end
```

Hope this proves helpful to someone else who also needs `wont_raise`.  Cheers!  :)

Comment: getting undefined method `infect_an_assertion' here, help?