# How to assert that a Rails method will not throw a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

In my Rails application I am doing a unit test where I expect an error when calling a certain method.

```
test "sending a logout request while not logged should not return an error" do
  assert_nothing_raised do
    do_a_logout
  end
end
```

Problem is that the test keeps reporting as *Error* instead as of *Failure* when `do_a_logout` errors out.

The error is `NoMethodError: NoMethodError: undefined method 'forget' for nil:NilClass`

It comes from this method two or three levels below the `do_a_logout` call

```
def forget user
  user.forget
  cookies.delete :user_id
  cookies.delete :remember_token
end
```

Here, the error I am expecting is for `user` to be nil and fail when calling `forget`. How can I make the test report a *Failure* instead of an *Error*?

Comment: Could you include the code for the `do_a_logout` method in your question, there might actually be an error there.

Comment: And also please provide full error message which you see.

Comment: It's logical that the error is raised, as you say you are expecting an exception so the exception is raised, during application execution therefore execution is terminated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [`assert_raise`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_raise) with the exception class you're expecting:

```
assert_raise(NoMethodError) { do_a_logout }
```

**ETA:** If you want to test that no error was raised, you can use [assert_nothing_raised](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_nothing_raised):

```
assert_nothing_raised { do_a_logout }
assert_nothing_raised(NoMethodError) { do_a_logout }
```

However as pointed out [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499262/1569930) and [elsewhere](http://www.thagomizer.com/blog/2013/06/11/assert-nothing-raised.html), there is no good reason to use this assertion, because its redundant: you *never* expect an error to be raised, unless you specify otherwise.

Moreover, it gives a less helpful failure than simply running the spec without the assertion. In particular, running with `assert_nothing_raised` when an error occurs will give you a backtrace only to the `assert_nothing_raised` call, while running the spec without this assertion will give a backtrace to the actual error that's occurring.

Comment: This will correctly catch the exception and pass. But I want the test to **Fail** if the exception is thrown.

Comment: The test was not failing, it was reporting Error.

Answer (score 1):

based on @nus [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499259/why-doesnt-minitestspec-have-a-wont-raise-assertion#comment64180153_12499262),

```
test "sending a logout request while not logged should not return an error" do
  do_a_logout
  # assert true # optional
end
```

or

```
assert_silent { do_a_logout }
```